# is there anyone can help me in this python code?

Tags: python

Define a function that accepts a list (called numbers below) as input and return a list where each element is multiplied by 10.
In this case, you need to write a function that will work for arbitrary input. Before submitting your function to the grader, you may want to check that it returns the output that you expect by evaluating code similar to the following:

```
test_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
mult(test_numbers)
```

any help?

Comment: Make sure titles relate to content, forming a useful summary, and are not trivially true (and also irrelevant). See the How to Ask guide.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using the list comprehension.

```
def multiply(lis):
    return [x * 10 for x in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
def multiply(input_list):
    return map(lambda a: a*10, input_list)

inp = map(int, input("Enter numbers seperated by comma(,):").split(','))

mul = multiply(inp)
for i in mul:
    print(i)
```